# Сохранение текущей вкладки Accordion при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте, есть вкладки, которые открываются с помощью Accordion.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/5ggs9d90/)

Код скрипта:

```
$(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
   });
});
```

К примеру этот Accordion используется в боковом меню. Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу, сохранялась открытая вкладка в Accordion?

Я нашел ответы на этот вопрос, но не пойму как реализовать. 
[ответы](https://php.ru/forum/threads/jquery-accordion.43922/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве реализации данного механизма можно добавлять параметр в URL при выборе элемента в вашем аккордионе

```
var url = document.location.href+"&active="+value;
```

В качестве параметра "page" можно добавить любое другое имя, а в значение "value" уже передавать значение, номер элемента или его Id

А при запуске страницы смотреть этот параметр и вызывать функцию для получения этого параметра и после его использовать для выделения элемента:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: А можно ли будет реализацию через                                                          
                                                                                                                       
   //получение значения active
var active = $(".selector").accordion( "option", "active" );       ?                                Т.е. изначально стоит значение active: false, после чего получает значения active.

Comment: @Anatoliy.CHA у вас получается несколько элементов с классом 'selector' и у каждого из них есть значение параметра аctive, которое принимает значения true или false, если я вас правильно понял. Если у вас активным может быть только один элемент, то можно передевать его номер или так же id, после чего при загрузке страницы этому элементу присваивать значение active=true

Comment: А можно будет пример реализации, когда через active=true? Если не сложно. )
А так, спасибо за ответ. )